# Using Generating Functions to solve Recurrence Relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The number of edges in the $k$-dimensional cube $Q_k$ (which is an important structure in network design, but you don't need to know the structure to solve this) can be found by the recurrence relation: $e(Q_1) = 1$; $e(Q_n) = 2e(Q_{n-1}) + 2n-1$ for $n>2$. Use generating functions to solve this recurrence relation and determine the number of edges in the $k$-dimensional cube.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you mean $2^{n-1}$ rather than $2n-1$?

Comment: Yes! So sorry..

Comment: What is the definition of $e(Q_2)$?

Comment: Denote $e(Q_0) = 0$. Let $F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty e(Q_i)x^i$. Then $F(x) - 2xF(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (e(Q_i) - 2e(Q_{i-1})x^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{i-1}x^i$.